# After monkeying around with headers/footers, how do I go back to normal editing?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

In Microsoft Word, I can edit headers and footers.  Now the main body of the document is grayed out.  There does not seem to be any 'done' button or way of going back to normal editing.  What is the trick?

Answer (score 2):

You double-click in the document body.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have many option to do:

- Keyboard shortcut fans do: Press `Esc`
- Menu fans do: Button `Close Header and Footer` in the Ribbon.
- Mouse fans do: Double-click in the document's body